# What's so special in "near field" and is it used in Near Field Communication?

Tags: wireless, radio, nfc

There's this commercial technology called [Near Field Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication). Turns out there're also so-called [near and far field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field). Near field (in near and far field) is special in that electrical and magnetic fields are in some complex relation while in near field region unlike in all outer space.

What I miss are two things.

Is the "near field" phrasing in NFC abbreviation really that "near field" with special relation between fields? What's so special in "near field" that makes it especially usable for communication - I mean why not just use a weak radio transmitter to limit distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "near field" in NFC simply refers to the close proximity of the communicating devices. It's just a commercial name.

When talking about transmission systems there's the "near field" opposite the "far field". The near field extends to about 1 wavelength away from the antenna, the far field starts from about 2 wavelengths away. The difference is that in the near field the transmitter can sense when radiated energy is being absorbed, while in the far field this isn't possible. This near field effect is used in RFID, where the tag "sends" a code to the reader by pulse-wise loading the carrier. In the far field this won't work.

Comment: 1 wavelength is extreme proximity - how do those RFID systems manage to achieve it?

Comment: @sharptooth - the limiting factor in RFID isn't the wavelength, but the power. Wavelength at 125kHz is 2400m, at 13.5MHz it's 22m, so RFID communication is really in the near field, even in warehouse applications where the tag is read at a few meters distance.

Answer (score 5):

NFC / Near Field Communication **is** a very special subset of electromagnetic communications (not just a marketing term - although many purveyors probably have no idea of the underlying differences between NFC and "proper" RF).

Note that NFC (Near Field Communications) is essentially technically identical to another "buzz word" technology IPT - Inductive Power Transfer. The difference is more applications emphasis that technology - both are mentioned below and information on one will be useful to understanding aspects of the other.

As you note, at close proximity to the antenna (how close varies somewhat with antenna design and other parameters) the relationship between magnetic and electric field components has not "settled" down to that which is experienced in "free space". (Note that this is another way of looking at the same relationship as explained (superbly) in the reference below which talks in terms of the "flatness" of the radiation pattern.

In free space the fixed relationship gives rise to the characteristic impedance of ~= 377 ohms.
  [Wikipedia on impedance of free space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space) - **warning:** Maxwell lurks here :-).

Here is a [superb explanation of WHY far field impedance settles down to a (nearly) constant value](http://www.phys.hawaii.edu/~anita/new/papers/militaryHandbook/antnrfld.pdf)  and where it breaks down (under about 1/6th wavelength) and the implications. They say (somewhat edited by me) -

- As noted in the sections on RF propagation and the radar equation, electromagnetic radiation expands
  spherically.
- When the range is large, the spherical surface of uniform power density appears flat to a receiving antenna
  which is very small compared to the surface of the sphere.  This is why the far field wave front is considered planar and
  the rays approximately parallel.  Also, it is apparent that at some shorter range, the spherical surface no longer appears
  flat, even to a very small receiving antenna.
- The distances where the planer, parallel ray approximation breaks down is known as the near field.  The
  crossover distance between near and far fields (R ) is taken to be where the phase error is 1/16 of a wavelength, or about 22.5 degrees

  Radius_near/far crossover = 2 x D^2 / wavelength

  where D is the largest dimension of the transmit antenna.

For interest, the near field of the Jodrell Bank Radio Telescope extends into near-earth space, making it "hard" to test it with intra solar system spacecraft communications systems which the dish is designed to interact with, prior to launch.

**BUT**

The (probably) most significant implication of working well within the near field was mentioned in passing by Steven. In the NF coupling is largely magnetic. No energy is dissipated in a magnetic field unless the field is "loaded". A NF "transmitter" can  operate at low power level until a tuned circuit couples to the field. At this point "transmitter" power level will need to be increased to maintain drive voltage level (or will automatically increase in a system with low impedance drive to the transmit "tank" circuit. The corollary of this is that the presence of a receiver can be detected by the effect on the transmitter. Receiving **IS** transmitting effectively.

Also, for explicit power transfer operations such as laptop of other battery charging the transmit power level can be low when unloaded,  be increased by loading - such as when a laptop etc is presented for charging, and decrease when the target is charged and elects to stop accepting current. This is the area dealt with by "Inductive power Transfer" (IPT)

- [Wikipedia - good discussion of Wireless Energy Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_energy_transfer) - See "Electrodynamic Induction Method" - I'd query some fine points. Note reference to near field - **excellent references and timeline**.
- [Wireless power consortium overview](http://www.wirelesspowerconsortium.com/technology/how-it-works.html) - note that this severely contradicts itself (and me in one case :-) ) over standby power.
- Youtube - [extremely good Inductive Power Transfer demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ODW-ntPHSU).

These characteristics of near field coupling which may seem "a bit magic" when seen from an RF perspective, seem entirely normal when seen from a transformer coupling perspective.

A difference to normal transformer coupling practice (and much closer to what is seen with RF) is that power transfer can be very much improved by resonating the receiver coil.

Higher "Q" allows greater range. Power transmissions at distances of metres are possible at high Q. I don't have details of Tesla's Crystal Palace equipment but reports sound like he may have managed even further. Warning - much material on Tesla on web is bunkum.
 Diagram below - Tesla "magnifier" -

[image]

Involvement of free space impedance on typical antenna impedances are discussed in

- [Wikipedia on Patch Antennae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_antenna)

  - [General brief antenna discussion](http://www.tpub.com/content/neets/14182/css/14182_178.htm)

---

Near Field power transfer system - they don't use the term anywhere in the [associated page](http://courses.cit.cornell.edu/bionb440/FinalProjects/f2005/bgh6/Signal%20Generator/page1/page1.html)

[image]

---

Philips PN532 NFC communications system.
  [NXP Near Field Communication 
(NFC) for handheld devices and 
POS terminals PN53 - Datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/acrobat_download2/literature/9397/75016623.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

NFC is just an commercial name - abbreviation to express that the communication distance is short - usually less then 10 cm. The distance for the transmitter is kept short, since the NFC comes with certain use cases which required this and short range helps keep the data secure. It has its roots in RFID technology and shared some standards with it, e.g. it operates  at 13.56 MHz on ISO/IEC 18000-3 air interface like some RFID tags/readers as well - it keeps it partly compatible.

BR
STeN